# Convert foreach to LINQ for practice and learning purposes

Tags: c#, linq

I wrote this code. It works. It is easy to read and easy to debug.
However for learning purposes for a few hours today I tried to convert it to some sort of LINQ with `JOIN` or `GroupJoin` or something like that. Because if you look at the `WHERE` clause my gut is telling me I could do that with some sort of `JOIN` maybe and get rid of `foreach` but well I could not come up with that syntax.

So I wanted to see if you can help me re-write it that way?

```
foreach (var f in myData)
{
    var res = new FinalClass
    {
        ID = f.ID,
        Floor = f.Floor,
        Description = f.Description
    };

    var setOne = setOneDataList.Where(b => b.FieldID == f.ID).Select(t => new CommonClass
    {
        FieldName = t.Field,
        Color = t.Color,
        Status = t.Status
    }).OrderBy(b => b.FieldName);

    var setTwo = setTwoDataList.Where(f => f.FieldID == f.ID).Select(t => new CommonClass
    {
        FieldName = t.Field,
        Color = t.Color,
        Status = t.Status
    }).OrderBy(b => b.FieldName);


    res.SetOne = setOne;
    res.SetTwo = setTwo;   

    result.Add(fs);
}
```

Comment: What's `fs`? `result.Add(fs);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took to long and I see someone already pasted the answer :)

But I'll submit mine, since I suggest using "one . per line" approach to writing LINQ. Don't you think it's more readable this way?

```cs
myData.Select(f => new FinalClass
{
    ID = f.ID,
    Floor = f.Floor,
    Description = f.Description,
    SetOne = setOneDataList
        .Where(b => b.FieldID == f.ID)
        .Select(t => new CommonClass
        {
            FieldName = t.Field,
            Color = t.Color,
            Status = t.Status
        })
        .OrderBy(b => b.FieldName),
    SetTwo = setTwoDataList
        .Where(f => f.FieldID == f.ID)
        .Select(t => new CommonClass
        {
            FieldName = t.Field,
            Color = t.Color,
            Status = t.Status
        })
        .OrderBy(b => b.FieldName),
};
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for join, but you can simply inline the inner calls:

```
var result = myData.Select(f => new FinalClass
{
    ID = f.ID,
    Floor = f.Floor,
    Description = f.Description,
    SetOne = setOneDataList.Where(b => b.FieldID == f.ID).Select(t => new CommonClass
      {
        FieldName = t.Field,
        Color = t.Color,
        Status = t.Status
      }).OrderBy(b => b.FieldName),
    SetTwo = setTwoDataList.Where(f => f.FieldID == f.ID).Select(t => new CommonClass
      {
        FieldName = t.Field,
        Color = t.Color,
        Status = t.Status
      }).OrderBy(b => b.FieldName)
});
```

Feel free to reuse the inner transformation:

```
Func<Data, CommonClass> makeCommonClass = t => new CommonClass
{
  FieldName = t.Field,
  Color = t.Color,
  Status = t.Status
};

// ...
SetOne = setOneDataList.Where(b => b.FieldID == f.ID).Select(makeCommonClass).OrderBy(b => b.FieldName),
```

Or write a function to extract and transform the relevant data:

```
IEnumerable<CommonClass> WithId(string id, IEnumerable<Data> list) {
  return list.Where(f => f.FieldID == id)
             .Select(t => new CommonClass
             {
               FieldName = t.Field,
               Color = t.Color,
               Status = t.Status
             })
             .OrderBy(b => b.FieldName)
}

var result = myData.Select(f => new FinalClass
{
    ID = f.ID,
    Floor = f.Floor,
    Description = f.Description,
    SetOne = WithId(f.ID, setOneDataList),
    SetTwo = WithId(f.ID, setTwoDataList)
});
```

Comment: For that matter, you could create an extension method that took care of the `Where`, `Select`, and `OrderBy` too :)

Comment: this is getting nice.

Comment: I am not good at Func and delegate either.  Can you use it in oyur solution ? instead of the psedu-code part I mean.  So I can see how it falls into place. Thanks.

Comment: @Bohn which pseudo-code part? There's no pseudo-code in my answer, that should be 100% valid C# code

Comment: the Func<> code under "Feel free to reuse the inner transformation:" part.  I can just copy that like a function declaration ?

Comment: @Bohn That's a regular variable of type `Func<...>` holding a Function object. You can use a regular method too if you prefer

Comment: right, when I want to embed the code in that part `Func<Data, CommonClass>` , it can't resolve the `Data`  . So I don't know what type is that

Comment: I see the confustion. That "Data"'s type is different classes for each of those sets HOWEVER the common part that I need is the same in those classes.

Comment: @Bohn in that case your only option is to repeat the stream for both enumerables. Unless you have an interface that's implemented by the elements of both enumerables? Then you could use a generic function to handle both cases.